# Magento show custom attribute selected value while navigating from cart edit page

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

**Question:** I want to display the custom attribute selected values when clicking edit button from cart page

Where I want to configure custom attribute to display the selected option ?

Ex: I have created new custom attribute called as "car model" dropdown in backend, for each product they will select the "model" dropdown values.

In frontend, "model" attribute will display as dropdown depend on the each product selected values.

I will saved the selected attribute value to the cart, have problem when editing the added product from the cart.

I need idea for how to display the selected attribute value will be selected in product view page, when clicking the "Edit" button in cart page.

Comment: please explan  briefly

Comment: It's called custom option and already works as you describe. Look for the "Custom Options" tab in product management, don't create a product attribute for "car model" (unless you really want to have one separate stock unit per attribute value, then you are looking for configurable products)

Comment: have you got any proper solution for this question?

Comment: No, I have searched with paid extension but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, I believe a configurable product is what you're searching for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for custom attribute option in simple product.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Custom Option is one of the possible ways to achieve functionality you want.
Regular Custom Product Attributes will not be suitable for your task because of these reasons:

- they can't be edited the Product Page, so they can't be edited on Cart Edit page also
- even if you customize Magento and allow editing of Custom Product Attribute it will affect globally (on Product stored in admin)

But probably you need a configurable product creation. Slightly more info about your business logic is needed to answer your question completely.

Comment: I tried with custom options but "car model" attribute value will vary depends on the selected "year" attribute values. So it will look like as  metioned hirearchy "year", "model", "make", etc. Then I created custom attribute for this requirement. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: So you can create configurable product with several configurable attributes: Year, Model, Make... Magento will filter unavailable options on product page.

Comment: Yes, we will achieve through configurable product. But depend on the year attribute image will change for each product, if I use configurable product I have to upload more images for each configurable product. So that I have choose simple product and return jQuery for image changing based on year. Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: For now I see  you have several attributes and you want to see dependency properly working: 
you choose Year and it shows you only appropriate models
then you choose model and it shows you only appropriate "make", right?
I think you should think about some "DependentAttribiutes" paid Magento Extensions, I saw them previously.

Comment: Yes I am also searching the extension for this, Thanks.